# Having isolated or non-reactive columns inside of a reactive dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, reactive

I have a reactive dataframe (called `selected_df()`) in which I am trying to consolidate information from `input$tableID_cells_selected` and another dataframe.

The second reactive dataframe, called `storage_df()`, is 1 row and 2 columns. It collects the background color and text labels from action buttons that are pressed, and then that data stays static in `storage_df()` until a different button is pressed.

`selected_df()` then collects the info about whatever button was last pressed from `storage_df()` when a cell in the table is selected (or whenever `input$plate_cells_selected` is updated), and shows these data in the same row.

The problem is that the `selected_df()` must reference `storage_df()` inside of the reactive environment, so it updates all of the values in the `cond_selected` and `color_selected` columns from `selected_df()`. I don't want to have those old values from `storage_df()` updated and replaced with whatever new values exist in `storage_df()`. I want those old rows of `selected_df()` to keep those old values, and for the new rows of `selected_df()` to have the new values of `storage_df()`. So basically, `storage)df()` is updated upon button click, as it is reactive, but the references to `storage_df()` made by `selected_df()` would not be reactive.

I have a gif here that will hopefully explain what I am trying to do, in case this is confusing. This is a previous attempt but it is the closest that I have gotten to success. In the gif, the color and cond columns of `selected_df()` are set such as follows for example: `cond_selected = isolate(paste0(rep(storage_df()[[1,2]])))`, so that value changes when a new button is pressed. The first three rows of column `cond_selected` within `selected_df()` should ideally stay gse1, while the latter three rows should be cox8a. As you can see, this is not what happens.

[image]

In other words, this is what I have in these columns at the end of this gif:
[image]

And this is what I want in these columns:

[image]

With my latest attempt (included in my MRE). I thought if I were to only try to update the values of the last added row, as I think the `selected_df()` might be appended whenever a new cell is selected, then that might work. However, the app crashes and only gives this warning, which it usually gave because `selected_df()` had no rows before a cell was selected:

```
Warning: Error in [: subscript out of bounds
```

Also, here is my MRE and latest attempt, and what I currently need help trying to figure out:

```
library(shiny)
library(colourpicker)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(glue)
library(shinyWidgets)


####Create the matrix and organization for the 96 well plate####
plate96 <- function(id) {
  div(
    style = "position: relative; height: 500px",
    tags$style(HTML('
          
        .wells {
            transform: translateX(50%);
        }

        .wells table.dataTable tr:nth-child(9) td { /*for the row 9, need to make it not look like a row*/
            border-bottom: unset;
        }

        .wells tbody tr td:not(:first-of-type) {
            border: 1px solid black;
            height: 15px;
            width: 15px;
            padding: 15px;
            font-size: 0;
        }
    ')),
    div(
      style = "position: absolute; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-100%);",
      div(
        class = "wells",
        DTOutput(id, width = "90%", height= "100%")
      )
    )
  )
}

####Create the matrix and organization for the 96 well plate####

renderPlate96 = function(id, colors = rep("white", 108)) {
  
  plate <- matrix(1:108, 
                  nrow = 9, 
                  ncol = 12, 
                  byrow = TRUE, 
                  dimnames = list(LETTERS[1:9], 1:12))
  
  colnames (plate) = stringr::str_pad(colnames(plate), 2, "left", "0")
  
  return(plate_return1 <-
           datatable(
             plate,
             options = list(dom = 't', ordering = F),
             selection = list(mode = 'multiple', 
                              target = "cell"),
             class = 'cell-border compact'
           ) %>%
           formatStyle(
             1:12,
             cursor = 'pointer',
             backgroundColor = styleEqual(1:108, colors, default = NULL)
           )
  )
}

storage_df <- (data.frame(
  matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = 1),
  color_selected = NA,
  cond_selected = NA
))

# app code
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  plate96("plate"),
  tags$b("Wells Selected:"),
  verbatimTextOutput("plateWells_selected"),
  
  br(),
  helpText("Step 1: Add in a couple of buttons"),
  numericInput("num_conds", 
               label = h3("Enter the number of treatments/ conditions"),
               min = 1,
               max = 20,
               value = 1),
  
  htmlOutput("cond_buttons", align = 'center'),
  
  helpText("Step 2: Type in any name for a condition for the buttons"),
  uiOutput("boxes_conds"),
  
  helpText("Step 3: Choose any color for the buttons"),
  uiOutput("cond_colors"),
  
  helpText("Step 4: Select cells from the table above"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("selected_table"),
  
  DT::dataTableOutput("storage_table"),

)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  ### ★★ ↓↓↓↓ PROBLEM AREA ↓↓↓↓ ★★ ###
  
  ####Storage data.frame for when the buttons are clicked####
  observeEvent(input$num_conds, {
    lapply(1:input$num_conds, function(x){
      
      observeEvent(input[[paste0("cond_buttons",x)]], {
        newdf <- tibble(
          color_selected =  input[[paste0("colors",x)]],
          cond_selected = input[[paste0("condID",x)]]
        )
        storage_df(newdf)
      })
    })
  })
  
  storage_df <- reactiveVal(tibble::tribble(
    ~color_selected, ~cond_selected
  ))
  
  output$storage_table <- renderDataTable(
    req(storage_df()), 
    options = list(paging = FALSE, 
                   ordering = FALSE, 
                   scrollx = FALSE,
                   searching = FALSE,
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
  )
  
  
  ####Create a DT that stores the values of the cells selected in the plate####
  selected_df <- reactive(data.frame(rows = req(input$plate_cells_selected[,1]),
                                     columns = req(input$plate_cells_selected[,2]),
                                     color_selected = 0,
                                     cond_selected = 0,
                                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
  )
  
####Take out this portion of the code if trying to reproduce my GIF###
  observeEvent(input$plate_cells_selected, {
    selected_df() %>% mutate(selected_df(), color_selected = replace(color_selected, color_selected== '0', isolate(paste0(rep(storage_df()[[1,1]]))))
    
  )})
####Take out this portion of the code if trying to reproduce my GIF###

  
  output$selected_table <- renderDataTable(
    req(selected_df()),
    options = list(paging = FALSE, 
                   ordering = FALSE, 
                   scrollx = FALSE,
                   searching = FALSE,
                   lengthChange = FALSE
    )
  )
  ### ★★ ↑↑↑↑ PROBLEM AREA ↑↑↑↑ ★★ ###
  
  #....#
  
  #Past here isn't as important to the question...#
  
  ####Input for user browse and data upload####
  output$contents <- renderTable({ req(input$data)  })
  
  #####Slider for frames per second####
  output$value <- renderPrint({ input$Frames })
  
  #####Check boxes for no-movement cell exclusion####
  output$value <- renderPrint({ input$emptyWell_checkbox })
  
  #####Number output for number of conditions#####
  output$value <- renderPrint({ input$num_conds })
  
  #### Condition boxes for UI text input####
  output$boxes_conds <- renderUI({
    num_conds = as.integer(input$num_conds)
    
    lapply(1:num_conds, function(i) {
      cond_names <- textInput(paste0("condID", i),
                              label = paste0("Treatment/ Conditions: ", i),
                              placeholder = "Enter condition..."
      )
    })
  })
  
  #### Color selection for UI input####
  output$cond_colors <- renderUI({
    num_conds = as.integer(input$num_conds)
    
    lapply(1:num_conds, function(i) {
      colourInput(paste0("colors", i),
                  label = (paste0("Select a color for condition ", i)),
                  show = c("both"),
                  value = "black",
                  palette = c("limited"),
      )
    })
  })
  
  #### Create action buttons for conditions to be selected####
  output$cond_buttons <- renderUI({
    num_conds = as.integer(input$num_conds)
    
    lapply(1:num_conds, function(i) {
      
      bg = input[[paste0("colors", i)]]
      style = paste0(
        collapse = " ",
        glue("background-color:{bg};
                  color:#ffffff;
                  border-color:#000000")
      )
      
      label = input[[paste0("condID", i)]]
      
      actionButton(paste0("cond_buttons", i),
                   label = label,
                   style = style, 
      )
    })
  })
  
  ####Create the 96 well plate image####
  output$plate <- renderDT({
    renderPlate96()
  })
  
  output$plateWells_selected <- renderPrint({
    input$plate_cells_selected
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**UPDATE UPON REQUEST**

Here is a portion of the code needed to reproduce what you see in the GIF. This is not my latest attempt and is not what I need help with troubleshooting, this is merely to give what I used to make the GIF that explains what I want. Just replace the similar version of the code with this in my MRE and take out the mutate function. The mutate function to remove has been marked by comments in my MRE.

```
####Create a DT that stores the values of the cells selected in the plate####
  selected_df <- reactive(data.frame(rows = req(input$plate_cells_selected[,1]),
                                     columns = req(input$plate_cells_selected[,2]),
                                     color_selected = isolate(paste0(rep(storage_df()[[1,1]]))),
                                     cond_selected = isolate(paste0(rep(storage_df()[[1,2]]))),
                                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  )
```

**UPDATE, REPONSE TO YBS**
[image]
[image]

Comment: It is not clear of your needs.  Each time you select a cell, what are you expecting? [in storage_df() and selected_df()]

Comment: Assuming that the condition fields and color selector have been updated so the storage_df() is populated, I'm wanting the values for color and condition columns inside selected_df() to reflect what the values were for storage_df() in the similarly named columns at the time when the cells were chosen instead of what they are currently, or when a new cell is selected. Essentially, I want selected_df() to store what the values of storage_df() were at the time when cells in the plate table were selected.

Comment: I added some more details to try and clarify my goals

Comment: Your code is not reproducible, as I am not getting what you get in your GIF.

Comment: I mentioned in my post that the gif was of a previous attempt and that the MRE was of my current attempt. I also posted the error that I am getting in my MRE, which is my current attempt. I posted as well the changes that I made in order to attain what I get in my GIF. All that would need to change is to include the code mentioned in that paragraph and remove the `observeEvent ` where I try the `mutate` function, since that is causing the error from my MRE.

Comment: I made these points more clear with my latest edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
# app code
ui <- fluidPage(

  plate96("plate"),
  tags$b("Wells Selected:"),
  verbatimTextOutput("plateWells_selected"),

  br(),
  helpText("Step 1: Add in a couple of buttons"),
  numericInput("num_conds",
               label = h3("Enter the number of treatments/ conditions"),
               min = 1,
               max = 20,
               value = 1),

  htmlOutput("cond_buttons", align = 'center'),

  helpText("Step 2: Type in any name for a condition for the buttons"),
  uiOutput("boxes_conds"),

  helpText("Step 3: Choose any color for the buttons"),
  uiOutput("cond_colors"),

  helpText("Step 4: Select cells from the table above"),
  DTOutput("selected_table"),

  DTOutput("storage_table"),

)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  ### ★★ ↓↓↓↓ PROBLEM AREA ↓↓↓↓ ★★ ###
  # storage_df <- reactiveVal(tibble::tribble(
  #   ~color_selected, ~cond_selected
  # ))

  storage_df <- reactiveVal(storage)

  ####Storage data.frame for when the buttons are clicked####
  observeEvent(input$num_conds, {
    lapply(1:input$num_conds, function(x){

      observeEvent(input[[paste0("cond_buttons",x)]], {
        newdf <- data.frame(
          color_selected =  input[[paste0("colors",x)]],
          cond_selected = input[[paste0("condID",x)]]
        )
        storage_df(newdf)
      }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
    })
  })

  output$storage_table <- renderDataTable(
    req(storage_df()),
    options = list(paging = FALSE,
                   ordering = FALSE,
                   scrollx = FALSE,
                   searching = FALSE,
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
  )

  selected <- reactiveValues(df=NULL,cum=NULL)
  df1 <- data.frame()
  
  observeEvent(input$plate_cells_selected, {
    n = dim(req(input$plate_cells_selected))[1]
    df1 <<- data.frame(rows = req(input$plate_cells_selected[,1]), columns = req(input$plate_cells_selected[,2]))
    
    ###Create a DT that stores the values of the cells selected in the plate####
    selected$cum <- rbind(selected$df,data.frame(rows = input$plate_cells_selected[n,1],
                                                 columns = input$plate_cells_selected[n,2],
                                                 color_selected = storage_df()[1,1], cond_selected = storage_df()[1,2]))

   
  }, ignoreNULL=FALSE)
  
  observeEvent(selected$cum, {
    n1 = dim(df1)[1]
    n2 = dim(selected$cum)[1]

    if (n1 > n2) { ##  add a row
      df <- selected$cum
    }else df <- left_join(df1, selected$cum, by=c("rows","columns"))
    selected$df <- df[!duplicated(df[,1:2]),] 
    #print(selected$df)
  })

  ####Create a DT that stores the values of the cells selected in the plate####
  # selected_df <- reactive(data.frame(rows = req(input$plate_cells_selected[,1]),
  #                                    columns = req(input$plate_cells_selected[,2]),
  #                                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% mutate(color_selected = c(0), cond_selected = c(0))
  # )

  output$selected_table <- renderDT(
    #selected_df(),
    selected$df,
    options = list(paging = FALSE,
                   ordering = FALSE,
                   scrollx = FALSE,
                   searching = FALSE,
                   lengthChange = FALSE
    )
  )
  ### ★★ ↑↑↑↑ PROBLEM AREA ↑↑↑↑ ★★ ###

  #....#

  #Past here isn't as important to the question...#

  ####Input for user browse and data upload####
  output$contents <- renderTable({ req(input$data)  })

  #####Slider for frames per second####
  output$value <- renderPrint({ input$Frames })

  #####Check boxes for no-movement cell exclusion####
  output$value <- renderPrint({ input$emptyWell_checkbox })

  #####Number output for number of conditions#####
  output$value <- renderPrint({ input$num_conds })

  #### Condition boxes for UI text input####
  output$boxes_conds <- renderUI({
    num_conds = as.integer(input$num_conds)

    lapply(1:num_conds, function(i) {
      cond_names <- textInput(paste0("condID", i),
                              label = paste0("Treatment/ Conditions: ", i),
                              placeholder = "Enter condition..."
      )
    })
  })

  #### Color selection for UI input####
  output$cond_colors <- renderUI({
    num_conds = as.integer(input$num_conds)

    lapply(1:num_conds, function(i) {
      colourInput(paste0("colors", i),
                  label = (paste0("Select a color for condition ", i)),
                  show = c("both"),
                  value = "black",
                  palette = c("limited"),
      )
    })
  })

  #### Create action buttons for conditions to be selected####
  output$cond_buttons <- renderUI({
    num_conds = as.integer(input$num_conds)

    lapply(1:num_conds, function(i) {

      bg = input[[paste0("colors", i)]]
      style = paste0(
        collapse = " ",
        glue("background-color:{bg};
                  color:#ffffff;
                  border-color:#000000")
      )

      label = input[[paste0("condID", i)]]

      actionButton(paste0("cond_buttons", i),
                   label = label,
                   style = style,
      )
    })
  })

  ####Create the 96 well plate image####
  output$plate <- renderDT({
    renderPlate96()
  })

  output$plateWells_selected <- renderPrint({
    input$plate_cells_selected
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! There is an issue with the table selection. If the condition values change, then the selected_df still remembers the old values. Also, selected_df remembers the values of cells that were selected previously, even after they are deselected. When cells are deselected after another button is pushed, rather than the value disappearing from selected_df, it updates the color and condition values in selected_df to the new values. I'll put a new GIF and picture in the question so you can see what I mean.

Comment: I do appreciate you working so hard on this so far though.

Comment: Also I noticed that if I selected [1,1], then [1,2], and then deselect [1,2] then selected_df() adds another row with [1,1]. I'm trying to play around with it and see if I can figure it out, but if you happen to have any time to troubleshoot, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Haha You are a saint. I'm a man of my word and did offer to send you doughnut funds, so I'll have that for you.

Comment: Please try the updated code.  Now it works when you deselect.  However, you need to set `selected$df` to `NULL` when all the selected cells are deselected.

Comment: Holy cow. How long did you spend on this? I'm amazed. I might add another GIF to the original post just so I can brag about your answer to this. I'm serious about that doughnut though. I'll drop my email for a couple of hours tomorrow in the comments and then delete it if that's acceptable.

Comment: I have another question about your code. Would the proper way to refer to one of the cells in the resulting data frame be something like `selected$df[1,2]`, as an example? Or

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Just try and play with different options, if you are not sure.

Comment: Hmmm. OK. So far that isn't working with what I am trying next. But if I can't find a way to make it work then I'll ask a few question. Thanks!