# Shiny app: Using indices listed in one dataframe for use in a replace function targeted at another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, shiny

This is in reference to the code written by YBS in another question. If YBS happens to see this and is interested/has the time to answer, I would love to hear your input :D

[Having isolated or non-reactive columns inside of a reactive dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73298172/having-isolated-or-non-reactive-columns-inside-of-a-reactive-dataframe/73314827?noredirect=1#comment129589213_73314827)

I have a dataframe called `storage$df` that stores the indices of selected cells of a datatable. It also stores the values of a reactive dataframe called `storage_df()`, and keeps those values constant after they are added to `storage$df` (thanks again to YBS).

I am trying to use the values in `selected$df` to replace data in a couple of dataframes (`colors_df` and `conds_df`) that match the dimensions of the original datatable (`plate`), but include the values from `selected$df` as further explained below:
[image]

I have been looking at trying to use `mapply` to make this work, but I haven't figured this out yet. As of now, I have a code that uses a system of `for` loops (which I know isn't ideal for dataframes, but I figured I may as well try the easy base option first) that works well when the values in `selected$df` are completely static and the loops are outside of an `observeEvent`. However, as soon as I implant the loops into an `observeEvent`, `colors_df` and `conds_df` are no
longer updated. I do not get an error message, however. I'm not sure if this is because I'm trying to use `for` loops inside of `observeEvent` or if I'm trying to index `selected$df` incorrectly.

Obviously, I would love to use whatever preferred methods there are. However, because of how I'm trying to use the indices from `selected$df` to replace data in my `colors_df` and `conds_df` tables, this has proven difficult to use apply variants (or at least I haven't figured it out yet).

Here is my reproducible example, sorry that it's a little long. I would normally cut it down more by taking out some of the reactives but I'm wondering they are part of the reason why this isn't working.

**NOTE:** There are instructional steps listed as `helpText` in the app to make it work.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(glue)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(colourpicker)
library(shinyjs)

####Create the matrix and organization for the 96 well plate####
plate96 <- function(id) {
  div(
    style = "position: relative; height: 500px",
    tags$style(HTML('
          
        .wells {
            transform: translateX(50%);
        }

        .wells table.dataTable tr:nth-child(9) td { /*for the row 9, need to make it not look like a row*/
            border-bottom: unset;
        }

        .wells tbody tr td:not(:first-of-type) {
            border: 1px solid black;
            height: 15px;
            width: 15px;
            padding: 15px;
            font-size: 0;
        }
    ')),
    div(
      style = "position: absolute; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-100%);",
      div(
        class = "wells",
        DTOutput(id, width = "90%", height= "100%")
      )
    )
  )
}

####Create the matrix and organization for the 96 well plate####

renderPlate96 = function(id, colors = rep("white", 108)) {
  
  plate <- matrix(1:108, 
                  nrow = 9, 
                  ncol = 12, 
                  byrow = TRUE, 
                  dimnames = list(LETTERS[1:9], 1:12))
  
  colnames (plate) = stringr::str_pad(colnames(plate), 2, "left", "0")
  
  return(plate_return1 <-
           datatable(
             plate,
             options = list(dom = 't', ordering = F),
             selection = list(mode = 'multiple', 
                              target = "cell"),
             class = 'cell-border compact'
           ) %>%
           formatStyle(
             1:12,
             cursor = 'pointer',
             backgroundColor = styleEqual(1:108, colors, default = NULL)
           )
  )
}


# app code
ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  
  plate96("plate"),
  tags$b("Wells Selected:"),
  DTOutput("selected_table"),
  
  verbatimTextOutput("plateWells_selected"),
  
  br(),
  helpText("Step 1: Add in a couple of buttons"),
  numericInput("num_conds",
               label = h3("Enter the number of treatments/ conditions"),
               min = 1,
               max = 20,
               value = 1),
  
  htmlOutput("cond_buttons", align = 'center'),
  
  helpText("Step 2: Type in any name for a condition for the buttons"),
  uiOutput("boxes_conds"),
  
  helpText("Step 3: Choose any color for the buttons"),
  uiOutput("cond_colors"),
  
  helpText("Step 4: Select cells from the table above"),
  
  DTOutput("storage_table"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("colors_table"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("conds_table"),
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  ### **** Problem Area **** ####
  observeEvent(req(input$plate_cells_selected), {
    delay(500,
          for(i in 1:nrow(selected$df)) {
            #For selecting any individual cells, coordinating the indices between the cell_selected and the conds and colors data.frames
            if (selected$df[i,1] < 9 && selected$df[i,2] > 0) {
              
              colors_df[selected$df[i,1], selected$df[i,2]] <- selected$df[i,3]
              conds_df[selected$df[i,1], selected$df[i,2]] <- selected$df[i,4]
            }
            
            #For selecting all cells in a row if the letters are selected
            else if (selected$df[i,2] == 0) { 
              
              for(x in seq(12)) {
                colors_df[selected$df[i,1], x] <- selected$df[i,3]
                conds_df[selected$df[i,1], x] <- selected$df[i,4]
              }
            }
            
            #For selecting all the cells in a column if the 9th cell is selected
            else if (selected$df[i,1] == 9) {
              
              for(x in seq(8)) {
                colors_df[x, selected$df[i,2]] <- selected$df[i,3]
                conds_df[x, selected$df[i,2]] <- selected$df[i,4]
              }
            }
          }       
  )})
  ###End problem area###


  ####Storage data.frame for when the buttons are clicked####
  storage <- (data.frame(
    color_selected = NA,
    cond_selected = NA
  ))
  
  storage_df <- reactiveVal(storage)
  
  observeEvent(input$num_conds, {
    lapply(1:input$num_conds, function(x){
      
      observeEvent(input[[paste0("cond_buttons",x)]], {
        newdf <- data.frame(
          color_selected =  input[[paste0("colors",x)]],
          cond_selected = input[[paste0("condID",x)]]
        )
        storage_df(newdf)
      }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
    })
  })
  
  output$storage_table <- renderDataTable(
    req(storage_df()),
    options = list(paging = FALSE,
                   ordering = FALSE,
                   scrollx = FALSE,
                   searching = FALSE,
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
  )
  
  selected <- reactiveValues(df=NULL,scope=NULL)
  df1 <- data.frame()
  
  observeEvent(input$plate_cells_selected, {
    n = dim(req(input$plate_cells_selected))[1]
    df1 <<- data.frame(rows = req(input$plate_cells_selected[,1]), 
                       columns = req(input$plate_cells_selected[,2]))
    
    ###Create a DT that stores the values of the cells selected in the plate####
    selected$scope <- rbind(selected$df,data.frame(rows = input$plate_cells_selected[n,1],
                                                   columns = input$plate_cells_selected[n,2],
                                                   color_selected = storage_df()[1,1], 
                                                   cond_selected = storage_df()[1,2],
                                                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
    
    
  }, ignoreNULL=FALSE)
  
  observeEvent(selected$scope, {
    n1 = dim(df1)[1]
    n2 = dim(selected$scope)[1]
    
    if (n1 > n2) { ##  add a row
      df <- selected$scope
    }else df <- left_join(df1, 
                          selected$scope, 
                          by=c("rows","columns"))
    
    selected$df <- df[!duplicated(df[,1:2]),] 
  })
  
  output$selected_table <- renderDT(
    selected$df,
    options = list(paging = FALSE,
                   ordering = FALSE,
                   scrollx = FALSE,
                   searching = FALSE,
                   lengthChange = FALSE,
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
  )
  
  ####data.frame for color information####
  colors_df <- data.frame(
    matrix(ncol = 12, nrow = 8)
  )
  
  output$colors_table <- renderDataTable(
    colors_df, 
    options = list(paging = FALSE, 
                   ordering = FALSE, 
                   scrollx = FALSE,
                   searching = FALSE,
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
  )
  
  ####data.frame for condition information####
  conds_df <- data.frame(
    matrix(ncol = 12, nrow = 8)
  )
  
  output$conds_table <- renderDataTable(
    conds_df, 
    options = list(paging = FALSE, 
                   ordering = FALSE, 
                   scrollx = FALSE,
                   searching = FALSE,
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
  )
  
  ####Input for user browse and data upload####
  output$contents <- renderTable({ req(input$data)  })
  
  #####Slider for frames per second####
  output$value <- renderPrint({ input$Frames })
  
  #####Check boxes for no-movement cell exclusion####
  output$value <- renderPrint({ input$emptyWell_checkbox })
  
  #####Number output for number of conditions#####
  output$value <- renderPrint({ input$num_conds })
  
  #### Condition boxes for UI text input####
  output$boxes_conds <- renderUI({
    num_conds = as.integer(input$num_conds)
    
    lapply(1:num_conds, function(i) {
      cond_names <- textInput(paste0("condID", i),
                              label = paste0("Treatment/ Conditions: ", i),
                              placeholder = "Enter condition..."
      )
    })
  })
  
  #### Color selection for UI input####
  output$cond_colors <- renderUI({
    num_conds = as.integer(input$num_conds)
    
    lapply(1:num_conds, function(i) {
      colourpicker::colourInput(paste0("colors", i),
                  label = (paste0("Select a color for condition ", i)),
                  show = c("both"),
                  value = "black",
                  palette = c("limited"),
      )
    })
  })
  
  #### Create action buttons for conditions to be selected####
  output$cond_buttons <- renderUI({
    num_conds = as.integer(input$num_conds)
    
    lapply(1:num_conds, function(i) {
      
      bg = input[[paste0("colors", i)]]
      style = paste0(
        collapse = " ",
        glue("background-color:{bg};
                  color:#ffffff;
                  border-color:#000000")
      )
      
      label = input[[paste0("condID", i)]]
      
      actionButton(paste0("cond_buttons", i),
                   label = label,
                   style = style,
      )
    })
  })
  
  ####Create the 96 well plate image####
  output$plate <- renderDT({
    renderPlate96()
  })
  
  output$plateWells_selected <- renderPrint({
    input$plate_cells_selected
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple issues here.  You need reactive dataframes to display the last two tables. You can use `local()` in a `for` loop (to deal with lazy evaluation) or `lapply` in an `observe`r. I have shown both examples here.  Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(glue)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(colourpicker)
library(shinyjs)

####Create the matrix and organization for the 96 well plate####
plate96 <- function(id) {
  div(
    style = "position: relative; height: 500px",
    tags$style(HTML('
          
        .wells {
            transform: translateX(50%);
        }

        .wells table.dataTable tr:nth-child(9) td { /*for the row 9, need to make it not look like a row*/
            border-bottom: unset;
        }

        .wells tbody tr td:not(:first-of-type) {
            border: 1px solid black;
            height: 15px;
            width: 15px;
            padding: 15px;
            font-size: 0;
        }
    ')),
    div(
      style = "position: absolute; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-100%);",
      div(
        class = "wells",
        DTOutput(id, width = "90%", height= "100%")
      )
    )
  )
}

####Create the matrix and organization for the 96 well plate####

renderPlate96 = function(id, colors = rep("white", 108)) {
  
  plate <- matrix(1:108, 
                  nrow = 9, 
                  ncol = 12, 
                  byrow = TRUE, 
                  dimnames = list(LETTERS[1:9], 1:12))
  
  colnames (plate) = stringr::str_pad(colnames(plate), 2, "left", "0")
  
  return(plate_return1 <-
           datatable(
             plate,
             options = list(dom = 't', ordering = F),
             selection = list(mode = 'multiple', 
                              target = "cell"),
             class = 'cell-border compact'
           ) %>%
           formatStyle(
             1:12,
             cursor = 'pointer',
             backgroundColor = styleEqual(1:108, colors, default = NULL)
           )
  )
}


# app code
ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  
  plate96("plate"),
  tags$b("Wells Selected:"),
  DTOutput("selected_table"),
  
  verbatimTextOutput("plateWells_selected"),
  
  br(),
  helpText("Step 1: Add in a couple of buttons"),
  numericInput("num_conds",
               label = h3("Enter the number of treatments/ conditions"),
               min = 1,
               max = 20,
               value = 1),
  
  htmlOutput("cond_buttons", align = 'center'),
  
  helpText("Step 2: Type in any name for a condition for the buttons"),
  uiOutput("boxes_conds"),
  
  helpText("Step 3: Choose any color for the buttons"),
  uiOutput("cond_colors"),
  
  helpText("Step 4: Select cells from the table above"),
  
  DTOutput("storage_table"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("colors_table"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("conds_table"),
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  ### **** Problem Area **** ####
  observeEvent(req(input$plate_cells_selected), {
    delay(500,
          for(i in 1:nrow(selected$df)) {
            local({
              i <- i
              #For selecting any individual cells, coordinating the indices between the cell_selected and the conds and colors data.frames
              if (selected$df[i,1] < 9 && selected$df[i,2] > 0) {
                
                colors$df[selected$df[i,1], selected$df[i,2]] <- selected$df[i,3]
                conds$df[selected$df[i,1], selected$df[i,2]] <- selected$df[i,4]
              }
              
              #For selecting all cells in a row if the letters are selected
              else if (selected$df[i,2] == 0) { 
                lapply(1:12, function(x){
                #for(x in seq(12)) {
                  colors$df[selected$df[i,1], x] <- selected$df[i,3]
                  conds$df[selected$df[i,1], x] <- selected$df[i,4]
                #}
                })
              }
              
              #For selecting all the cells in a column if the 9th cell is selected
              else if (selected$df[i,1] == 9) {
                lapply(1:8, function(x){
                #for(x in seq(8)) {
                  colors$df[x, selected$df[i,2]] <- selected$df[i,3]
                  conds$df[x, selected$df[i,2]] <- selected$df[i,4]
                #}
                })
              }
            })
            
          }       
    )})
  ###End problem area###
  
  
  ####Storage data.frame for when the buttons are clicked####
  storage <- (data.frame(
    color_selected = NA,
    cond_selected = NA
  ))
  
  storage_df <- reactiveVal(storage)
  
  observeEvent(input$num_conds, {
    lapply(1:input$num_conds, function(x){
      
      observeEvent(input[[paste0("cond_buttons",x)]], {
        newdf <- data.frame(
          color_selected =  input[[paste0("colors",x)]],
          cond_selected = input[[paste0("condID",x)]]
        )
        storage_df(newdf)
      }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
    })
  })
  
  output$storage_table <- renderDataTable(
    req(storage_df()),
    options = list(paging = FALSE,
                   ordering = FALSE,
                   scrollx = FALSE,
                   searching = FALSE,
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
  )
  
  selected <- reactiveValues(df=NULL,scope=NULL)
  df1 <- data.frame()
  
  observeEvent(input$plate_cells_selected, {
    n = dim(req(input$plate_cells_selected))[1]
    df1 <<- data.frame(rows = req(input$plate_cells_selected[,1]), 
                       columns = req(input$plate_cells_selected[,2]))
    
    ###Create a DT that stores the values of the cells selected in the plate####
    selected$scope <- rbind(selected$df,data.frame(rows = input$plate_cells_selected[n,1],
                                                   columns = input$plate_cells_selected[n,2],
                                                   color_selected = storage_df()[1,1], 
                                                   cond_selected = storage_df()[1,2],
                                                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
    
    
  }, ignoreNULL=FALSE)
  
  observeEvent(selected$scope, {
    n1 = dim(df1)[1]
    n2 = dim(selected$scope)[1]
    
    if (n1 > n2) { ##  add a row
      df <- selected$scope
    }else df <- left_join(df1, 
                          selected$scope, 
                          by=c("rows","columns"))
    
    selected$df <- df[!duplicated(df[,1:2]),] 
  })
  
  output$selected_table <- renderDT(
    selected$df,
    options = list(paging = FALSE,
                   ordering = FALSE,
                   scrollx = FALSE,
                   searching = FALSE,
                   lengthChange = FALSE,
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
  )
  
  ####data.frame for color information####
  colors <- reactiveValues(df =  data.frame(
    matrix(ncol = 12, nrow = 8)
  ))
  
  output$colors_table <- renderDataTable(
    colors$df, 
    options = list(paging = FALSE, 
                   ordering = FALSE, 
                   scrollx = FALSE,
                   searching = FALSE,
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
  )
  
  ####data.frame for condition information####
  conds <- reactiveValues(df = data.frame(
    matrix(ncol = 12, nrow = 8)
  ))
  
  output$conds_table <- renderDataTable(
    conds$df, 
    options = list(paging = FALSE, 
                   ordering = FALSE, 
                   scrollx = FALSE,
                   searching = FALSE,
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
  )
  
  ####Input for user browse and data upload####
  output$contents <- renderTable({ req(input$data)  })
  
  #####Slider for frames per second####
  output$value <- renderPrint({ input$Frames })
  
  #####Check boxes for no-movement cell exclusion####
  output$value <- renderPrint({ input$emptyWell_checkbox })
  
  #####Number output for number of conditions#####
  output$value <- renderPrint({ input$num_conds })
  
  #### Condition boxes for UI text input####
  output$boxes_conds <- renderUI({
    num_conds = as.integer(input$num_conds)
    
    lapply(1:num_conds, function(i) {
      cond_names <- textInput(paste0("condID", i),
                              label = paste0("Treatment/ Conditions: ", i),
                              placeholder = "Enter condition..."
      )
    })
  })
  
  #### Color selection for UI input####
  output$cond_colors <- renderUI({
    num_conds = as.integer(input$num_conds)
    
    lapply(1:num_conds, function(i) {
      colourpicker::colourInput(paste0("colors", i),
                                label = (paste0("Select a color for condition ", i)),
                                show = c("both"),
                                value = "black",
                                palette = c("limited"),
      )
    })
  })
  
  #### Create action buttons for conditions to be selected####
  output$cond_buttons <- renderUI({
    num_conds = as.integer(input$num_conds)
    
    lapply(1:num_conds, function(i) {
      
      bg = input[[paste0("colors", i)]]
      style = paste0(
        collapse = " ",
        glue("background-color:{bg};
                  color:#ffffff;
                  border-color:#000000")
      )
      
      label = input[[paste0("condID", i)]]
      
      actionButton(paste0("cond_buttons", i),
                   label = label,
                   style = style,
      )
    })
  })
  
  ####Create the 96 well plate image####
  output$plate <- renderDT({
    renderPlate96()
  })
  
  output$plateWells_selected <- renderPrint({
    input$plate_cells_selected
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I'm sure there are plenty of issues, but thank you for helping me with these ones. So I wouldn't need `local()` if I decide to stick with `lapply` instead of the `for` loop, is that correct? Also, is there a reason why the `colors_df` should be changed to `colors$df`? I get `Error in $: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable` if I use `$` in the function, but it still doesn't work if I change them back to `colors_df`

Comment: As `colors_df` is static, you cannot change the null values you set at the beginning.  `colors$df` is reactive, and changes with input change.  I get no errors with the above code that I posted.

Comment: Interesting, I have no idea what changed but I re-copy and pasted it and it works great now. Thank you again!

Comment: @Chris, Please accept the answer, if it worked for you.

Comment: Oops, my bad. Thanks for reminding me